# Is PrefixFreeNP=P?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np

I was given the following definition of a verifier:

> Verifier $V$ is called $PrefixFree$ if for every $x,y$ such that $V(x,y)=1$, then for every $y'$ (which is not an empty string, $y'\ne\epsilon$) $V(x,yy')=0$.

Based on the definition above we create the complexity class $PrefixFreeNP$ of all the decision problems that have a $PrefixFree$ NP verifier

I need to proof, disproof or show equivalency to an open question the following statement:

> P=PrefixFreeNP

My solution:
My idea is to show that $NP=PrefixFreeNP$ and then because $NP=P$ is an open question so is $P=PrefixFreeNP$.
To show that I need to proof (1) $PrefixFreeNP\subseteq NP$ and (2) $NP\subseteq PrefixFreeNP$.
To proof (1) is preety straight forward becuase I can just use the same verifier the problem has becuase it an $NP$ verifier.  For statement (2) this is my idea:
Given $S\in NP$, S has $NP$ verifier $V$. I'll define verifer $V'$ in the following manner:

1. Mark $y=y_1y_2\dots y_n$
2. If $V(x,y)=0$ or $V(x,y\circ 1) = 1$ or $V(x,y\circ 0)=1 $  return 0
3. for $i\gets 1$ to $n$:
   3.1 if $V(x,y_i)=1$ return 0
4. return 1

This is a proper verifier since we can only return 1 if $y$ is a solution to the problem and we check if y is prefix free by checking if y is created adding a string to a shorter solution, and by checking we can't add any string to y. Is my idea correct or should I try a different way of thinking?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.